# Multidimensional Array output to label

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array

Hi I'm having problems printing it to the label which is the output.text, it keeps coming out blank, but when I print to console it shows the number.

```
name.state = stateText.text

var stateName = [
["AK - Alaska", tax.alaska!],
["AL - Alabama", tax.alabama!],
["AR - Arkansas", tax.arkansas!],
["AZ - Arizona", tax.arizona!],
["CA - California", tax.california!]
]

for var i = 0; i < stateName.count; i++ {
if tax.state == stateName[i][0] {
    stateName[i][1] = Double(taxNumb.text!)!
    print(stateName[i][1])
    output.text = stateName[i][1] as? String
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't *cast* to `String`. What you have is a `Double`, that is not just castable to `String`.
You need to *create* a `String`:

```
output.text = String(stateName[0][1])
```

or

```
output.text = "\(stateName[i][1])"
```

Comment: what if the output keeps coming up as an optional, How can I unwrap it

Comment: @Karpisdiem either use an if-let around it, or use the `??` operator